# How do I hide the "Recently Modified" portion of the quick launch?

Tags: design, quick-launch

The "Recently Modified" section in the quick launch is not something I want my users to see.  How can I eliminate or hide it in a SharePoint 2010 installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accomplished this by using the steps outlined [here](http://john.dandison.com/blog/post/2010/01/25/Removing-the-e28098Recently-Modifiede28099-from-the-Quick-Launch-e28093-SharePoint-2010.aspx).

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\DocumentTemplates\`
2. Open `wkpstd.aspx` in a text editor.
3. Find `<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>` and replace with `<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges" visible="false"/>`.

If you ever need to reverse this process simply remove the `visible="false"` from the same tag.

**Edit:** As David pointed out in the comments this is not considered a "best practice" as updates from Microsoft can effectively undo the changes made to files in the 14 hive.  In theory, however, should an update reset your `wkpstd.aspx` file you could simply take these steps again to re-hide the Recently Modified section so long as the update didn't fundamentally change the tag that needs to be altered.

Comment: Can you do this with the Navigation option in Site Settings or is this not modifiable through there?  I've used that for our page navigation but haven't implemented wiki's yet, it'd be good to know if I'll need a different method to manipulate nav settings.

Comment: I'm _really_ new to SharePoint, but if I'm understanding your question correctly I think this solution should work for every quick launch or quick launch-esque structure throughout your site collection.  I haven't implimented wikis in my SP2010 install yet (and probably never will) so I haven't tested that, but I believe this worked for wikis when I demoed SP2007 a few months ago.  Your results may vary.

Comment: Directly modifying Microsoft files in the 14 hive is 'bad' for a number of reasons.  The most significant is that Microsoft can and will replace them in a future patch/update.

Comment: @David - I did not know that.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that this isn't considered a "best practice".

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of what David said, typically we avoid doing anything in the 14 hive except updated web.config's that we need changed for our customizations.

Comment: As 'wkpstd.aspx' is the only wiki template file for one SharePoint server, modifying it could cause problems for other site collections.

Answer (score 7):

I achieved this in a much more simple way.

Follow this link - really easy for beginers linke me...

http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-administrators-blog/hide-recently-modified-from-the-quick-launch

Edit page, insert content editor web part, edit source HTML of web part, paste in this HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .s4-recentchanges
 {
 display:none;
 }
 </style>
```

Set web part chrome type to "none," save and close.  Observe that the "Recently Modified" pages navigation is no longer showing on this page.

Comment: Please add a summary of the steps outlined in the link to your answer. If the link breaks in the future, your answer will no longer be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is an answer yes but this is really not a recommended way!
The best way would be to place the CSS from the other answer in you master page!

```
<style type="text/css">
 .s4-recentchanges
 {
 display:none;
 }
 </style>
```

This protects you from the setting beeing removed trough updates etc.

Comment: Now 2 years later I know that this could also be removed trough updates or upgrade of the SharePoint Version, so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found an easier way. Open the page in SPD, edit in advanced mode, and hover over the Recently Modified box in the Preview pane. Click on the > arrow to the right of the pane and select “Default to Master’s Content”. You’ll receive a notification saying that if you default to the Master Page content, everything in that region will be removed from the page. Click “Yes”.

[image: Default to Master's Content menu]

Then Save, go about your business, accept any additional nofications (for example, some sites will say “this will no longer match the site definition”) after determining that they are irrelevant, and reload the page. The ‘Recently Modified’ section is no longer there.

If this then causes a notification banner that the “current page has been customized from its template”, see [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/remove-revert-to-template-message-from-page/72370#72370) on how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following easy fix frequently

I create a security group called z_Blank with no members in it.
I subsequently restrict audience for the link to z_Blank.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to create a SharePoint group (I called mine "RemoveRecent") and have no users assigned to that group.

I then used this PowerShell script to add the "RemoveRecent" group into the "Audience Targeting" section of the "Recent" Quick Launch Navigation Link.

This effectively hides the menu item from everyone.

```
$Site = Get-SPSite "https://SITECOLLECTION/"

foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
    {
    $PublishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $QuickLaunchNav = $PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes
    $QuickLaunchHeading = $QuickLaunchNav | where {$_.Title -eq "Recent"} 

    if ($QuickLaunchHeading)
        {
        Write-Host $Web.Title "- " -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline
        $QuickLaunchHeading.Properties["Audience"] = "RemoveRecent"
        $QuickLaunchHeading.Update()
        Write-Host $QuickLaunchHeading.Properties["Audience"] -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Only put in you core css:

```
.s4-recentchanges
 {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```